# When taking the ferry from Shimonoseki, Japan to Busan, Korea, how much will I need in cash-only fees?

Tags: japan, south-korea, ferries, fees-and-charges, taxes

Seven years ago I took ferries between Japan and Korea about six times, and I'm looking at taking the ferry again.

I seem to recall that even when paying for the ferry ticket in cash that there is also some fee or tax that can only be paid in cash. I remember getting caught out by this once or twice and having to find an ATM at the last minute.

In 2019, when going in the direction from Japan to Korea, how much are these fees/taxes that I'll only be able to pay in JPY, so I can keep aside that amount when spending my last Japanese money?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always check the [Kampuferry website](http://www.kampuferry.co.jp/passenger/english/fare.html) for their fares and information.

Keep in mind the port facility charge and fuel surcharge, which are settled **only in cash** and collected directly at the counter of the company at the time of check-in, both in the Shimonoseki port and Busan port.

On that website you can also read about [the Passenger Tax for Promotion of International Tourism](http://www.kampuferry.co.jp/passenger/info/passengertaxeng.html). It's 1000 yen, cash only.

> **Collection**  Passengers over 2 years old  departing from Shimonoseki
>
> **Location**   Check-in counter on the 2nd floor of Shimonoseki International Terminal
>
> **Amount** 1,000 yen (cash only)
>
> Start date of collection : January 7, 2019  Customers departing from Shimonoseki

Comment: Aha so it looks like it will be 610 + 600 + 1000, for a total of 2200 JPY for an adult departing Japan.